# Loop Issues with JavaScript, Inserting values into array won't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
/*jshint multistr:true */
var myName = "Killa";
var text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Killa \
blah blah blah Killa blah blah Killa blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Killa";
var hits = [];
for (var i = 0; i > text.length; i++){
    if (text[i] == "K"){
        for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++){
            hits.push(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Why won't killa be pushed into the Hits array. Please help me. Changed text for security purposes. Sorry if it looks silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below fixes your problem and adds the "Killa" to the array Hits.

```
var myName = "Killa";
var text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Killa \
blah blah blah Killa blah blah Killa blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Killa";
var hits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if (text[i] == "K"){
        for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++){
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}


    console.log(hits);
```

Answer (score 6):

`i > text.length` should probably be `i < text.length`.